# How I can login with facebook and twitter but without curl extension?

Tags: php, facebook, twitter

How I can login with facebook and twitter but without curl extension? I need to login with facebook and twitter in a cloud system, so I need that without curl extension.

Comment: Check this: http://martinsikora.com/facebook-php-api-without-curl-extension

Answer (score 0):

Is it just curl not installed or is it your PHP configuration not allowing outgoing connections? It's worth checking that first.

You can also use sockets instead of curl, which are more low-level, but will allow you to achieve what you want.